# Deploy to multiple projects with one cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have 3 projects and I want my `deploy.cloudbuild.yaml` to deploy my app in all these projects(GKE).

Is it possible to deploy my app in all 3 projects? Also, I don't want to manage `cloudbuild` in all 3 projects.

Answer (score 1):

Please review this Stack thread - [How to deploy one app engine app to multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468221/how-to-deploy-a-container-to-multiple-gcp-projects-and-host-with-cloud-run).

Is this what you are trying to achieve but by means of GKE?
If so, it should be possible after adjusting the build steps.

Comment: It is resolved we have project tag that we can add in cloudbuild.yaml file 
 - id: 'Deploy image to kubernetes'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy'
    args:
    - run
    - --filename=[manifest location]
    - --location=[location]
    - --cluster=[cluster-name]
    - --project=[project-id]
we can specify project id and give cloudbuild SA other project access

Comment: @Abhinav that being the case please accept Farid's answer or create one of your own explaining what you did in details so that other users can easily refer to it if they also face this issue.